# Getting the first and last row?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

i have another query to select return min, max, start and end price.
It is for a specific month and works perfect for metal_id = 1 but when changed to 2, it returns no data.

please see:
The query below does its job to select the min, max, start and last price per day in a given month.

I would like to select the same but for the whole month, as in show the overall performance for the given month instead of on a daily basis.

Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bee86/1

I just need the last 2 prices, first and last price on the months selected...

```
select 
       highp.metal_price_datetime_IST AS high_price_metal_price_datetime_IST
     , highp.metal_price as highest_price
     , lowp.report_term
     , lowp.metal_price as lowest_price
     , lowp.metal_price_datetime_IST AS low_price_metal_price_datetime_IST
from (select @report_term:=concat(monthname(metal_price_datetime_IST), ' ', year(metal_price_datetime_IST)) as report_term
           , metal_price_datetime_IST
           , metal_price
           , metal_id
           , case when @report_term=@old_report_term then @rn1:=@rn1+1  else @rn1:=1 end as rn
           , @old_report_term:=@report_term
      from metal_prices
      cross join (select @rn1:=0, @old_report_term:='') inituservar1
      where datediff(now(), metal_price_datetime_IST) between 0 and 180
     and metal_id = 1
      order by metal_id, report_term, metal_price asc) lowp
inner join (select @report_term2:=concat(monthname(metal_price_datetime_IST), ' ', year(metal_price_datetime_IST)) as report_term
           , metal_price_datetime_IST
           , metal_price
           , metal_id
           , case when @report_term2=@old_report_term2 then @rn2:=@rn2+1  else @rn2:=1 end as rn
           , @old_report_term2:=@report_term2
      from metal_prices
      cross join (select @rn2:=0, @old_report_term2:='') inituservar1
      where  datediff(now(), metal_price_datetime_IST) between 0 and 180
            and metal_id = 1
      order by metal_id, report_term, metal_price desc) highp
 on lowp.rn=highp.rn
 and lowp.metal_id = highp.metal_id
 and lowp.report_term = highp.report_term
 and lowp.rn = 1

 order by lowp.metal_price_datetime_IST DESC
```

Comment: You need to give us a minimal problem.  This is a very large and complex query.

Comment: It is my only problem, i couldnt say anything else more or less...

Comment: Dean is correct, he has indicated his problem, demonstrated it, included what he wants and tried to tackle the problem too.